# Running "grep MH /proc/cpuinfo" - most CPUs Mhz are maxed on Fedora/Redhat

Tags: fedora, rhel, power-management, laptop, intel

After running:

> $ lscpu | grep MH

My 1280p Intel Processor running on Fedora 38 retunrs back:

```
CPU(s) scaling MHz:              91%
CPU max MHz:                     1800.0000
CPU min MHz:                     400.0000
```

So I run:

> grep MH /proc/cpuinfo

And my output is:

```
cpu MHz     : 444.752
cpu MHz     : 400.000
cpu MHz     : 920.638
cpu MHz     : 2000.000
cpu MHz     : 400.060
cpu MHz     : 2000.000
cpu MHz     : 400.256
cpu MHz     : 2000.000
cpu MHz     : 707.552
cpu MHz     : 2000.000
cpu MHz     : 1078.017
cpu MHz     : 2000.000
cpu MHz     : 820.163
cpu MHz     : 2000.000
cpu MHz     : 481.877
cpu MHz     : 2000.000
cpu MHz     : 2000.000
cpu MHz     : 2000.000
cpu MHz     : 2000.000
cpu MHz     : 2000.000
```

--- Why are so many high? I am under the assumption that "intel_pstate=passive" would be the correction for this issue but I cant seem to apply it. I have verified that I do have the technology via:

> cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver

What am I reading wrong or doing wrong because whenever I run:

> cpupower frequency-info

It returns:

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 1.80 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 400 MHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 418 MHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: no - diabled in UEFI
    Active: no - diabled in UEFI
```

Is it only displaying info for CPU 0? I have corrected Tunables and adjusted for powersaving features with "Tuned-utils" such as:

```
$sudo cpupower frequency-set --governor powersave
$tuned-adm profile powersave
$sudo powertop2tuned superpowersave -e --f
```

Aswell as rerunning the last command with "superpowersave" in place to possibly bypass any conflict and make sure the pwofiles are enabled since trying to save it with just *powersave* actually retuned this:

```
Running PowerTOP, please wait...
Generating shell script /etc/tuned/powersave/script.sh
Generating TuneD config file /etc/tuned/powersave/tuned.conf
New profile has same name as active profile, not including active profile (avoiding circular deps).
```

I have read up on: [Kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.13/admin-guide/pm/intel_pstate.html#passive-mode) & [Access.Redhat.com](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/monitoring_and_managing_system_status_and_performance/managing-power-consumption-with-powertop_monitoring-and-managing-system-status-and-performance) on the pstate and power configurations, but still looking for a little more professional guidance or support, please and thank you.